# How we can automate python client application which is used an an interface for user to call APIs

Tags: python, jmeter, pycharm

We have made an python client which is used as an interface for user. some function is defined in the client which internally calls the APIs and give output to users.

My requirement is to automate the python client - functions and validate the output.

Please suggest tools to use.

Comment: You can try **schedule**, one of the tools used for automation

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that:

- You can write multiple tests for your application as the **test cases** which are responsible to call your functions and get the result and validate them. It calls the **"feature test"**. To do that, you can use the python **"unittest"** library and call the tests periodically.
- If you have a web application you can use **"selenium"** to make automatic test flows. (Also you can run it in a **docker container virtually**)
- The other solution is to write another python application to call your functions or send requests everywhere you want to get the specific data and validate them. (It's the same with the two other solutions with a different implementation)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is using Python for this, the simplest solution would be a library like [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/). More comprehensive option would be something like [Robot framework](https://robotframework.org/)

Given you have [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) in your tags I assume that at some point you will want to make a performance test, however it might be easier to use [Locust](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing) for this as it's pure Python load testing framework.

If you still want to use JMeter it's possible to call Python programs using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)